# restore AWS RDS Postgres snapshot in google cloud SQL Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, google-cloud-sql

I have a Postgres DB (size is 1TB) that i want to duplicate into google cloud SQL Postgres.

How do I achieve this ?

I have taken a snapshot of the DB but I don't know how to transfer it to google cloud and create a Postgres DB from it

Answer (score 0):

Most of the market Cloud Services also offer transfer services. Since you are looking for migration into **GCP**

you can use google's storage transfer service for transferring data in TBs.

I suggest **compress the data if possible**

below links will help you to transfer files.

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/transferring-big-data-sets-to-gcp

https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check this official documentation where is explained how to migrate your database to Cloud SQL service[1]

Also, on this document you can find how to import data using CSV files too [2], I strongly recommend you take a look on the best practices for importing and exporting data too [3].

And here you can take a look on a very good example[4].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-postgresql-to-gcp

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing

[3] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/

[4] https://medium.com/faun/how-to-migrate-postgresql-databases-to-google-cloud- sql-81ae448dc086